# Xubuntu 18.04 not using Intel i915 video driver

Tags: xubuntu, xorg, intel

My previous install of Xubuntu 16.04 LTS would find and install the Xorg graphics video driver 'intel'.

However, my current install of Xubuntu 18.04 LTS does not find it.

It is using the 'framebuffer' driver :-(

The i915 module appears to be loaded...

```
i915                 1617920  19
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        167936  1 i915
drm                   401408  9 i915,drm_kms_helper
video                  40960  2 samsung_laptop,i915
```

... and the package 'xserver-xord-video-intel' is installed...

```
xserver-xorg-video-intel:
Installed: 2:2.99.917+git20171229-1
Candidate: 2:2.99.917+git20171229-1
Version table:
*** 2:2.99.917+git20171229-1 500
    500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

...any ideas how to get it using the actual Intel Video driver?

Thanks in advance.

Paully

Comment: At your login prompt, click the cog wheel, and select `Ubuntu on Xorg`. Report back. Also, know that if your select this, there may be a booting problem that might require that you use the lightdm display manager over gdm3. (I'm using Ubuntu terminology... it may be slightly different on Xubuntu).

Comment: Alas, I do not have this option on my Xubuntu 18.04. I am definitely NOT using the intel driver for Xorg Graphics:  Card: Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.6 drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1366x768@60.07hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Sandybridge Mobile version: 3.3 Mesa 18.0.0-rc5

Comment: I'm having the same issue with my Lenovo X220T, coming from 16.04 LTS. Fresh install of Xubuntu 18.04 LTS. @PaulLittlefield did you ever solve this? Or go to another distro, if so which?